# Merge dataframes based on date criteria in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frmaes (say DF1 and DF2). I want to merge them based on multiple criteria. If 'state' and 'city' of DF1 match that of DF2, and 'date' of DF2 is in within four years of 'date' of DF1, then I would like to add column 'margin' from DF2 to DF1. If the conditions are not met, column 'margin' of DF1 will have value of NA.

```
DF1 <- structure(list(date = c("2001-02-14", "2001-06-14", "2004-03-31", 
"2003-03-11", "2003-06-29"), state = c("DE", "NY", "NY", "NY", 
"AZ"), city = c("Wilmington", "New York", "Buffalo", "New York", 
"Phoenix"), industry = c("Retail", "Computers and Software", 
"Manufacturing (Misc.)", "Healthcare and Medical", "Construction and Supplies"
), SIC = c(5331, 3571, 2541, 8063, 2421)), row.names = c(2937L, 
2817L, 2117L, 2298L, 2228L), class = "data.frame")

DF2 <- structure(list(date = c("2000-11-07", "2000-11-07", "2008-11-04", 
"2000-11-07", "2000-11-07", "2008-11-04", "2004-11-02", "2004-11-02", 
"2008-11-04", "2012-11-06"), state = c("MA", "NY", "OH", "VA", 
"CA", "DE", "NY", "NY", "NY", "AZ"), city = c("Boston", "New York", 
"Cleveland", "Richmond", "Los Angeles", "Wilmington", "New York", 
"Buffalo", "New York", "Phoenix"), margin = c(-3.61895488477766, -41.5805022156573, -40.2049010106604, 
24.8839947364776, 17.2042747593408, -55.4514285714286, -35.5094126201826, 
-61.9743406985032, -39.9718177548145, 7.47655435915248)), row.names = c(9849L, 
10041L, 29268L, 11941L, 7365L, 31116L, 13227L, 17397L, 23352L, 
32571L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In your example, all the dates are within 4 years

Comment: also is the column `merge` referring to `margin`? both need to be clarified

Comment: Thanks @akrun. There are many observations in my sample, so I had to take a random sample. In this random sample, the dates might be withing 4 years, but in general they are not.

Comment: Thanks @EJJ. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Depending on how you want the interval.

```
 library(lubridate)
 library(fuzzyjoin)
    
        DF1$date <- ymd(DF1$date)     
        DF2$date <- ymd(DF2$date)       
        DF2$interval <- interval(DF2$date,  DF2$date + years(4))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        fuzzy_left_join(DF1, DF2, 
                        by = c("city" = "city",
                               "state" = "state",
                               "date" = "interval"),
                        match_fun = c(`==`, `==`, `%within%`))
```

Comment: Thanks @gravertje. With minor correction, it does work.